# 13.10 bricks Surface Pro?

Tags: installation, boot, grub2, uefi, surface

With the following method I was able to brick 2 different Surface Pros with the exact same methods.

1. you shrink your partition on Windows and disable those 2 secure-boot/uefi settings from the advanced startup screen.
2. boot from a usb stick and install Ubuntu as you should (wireless not working as reported).
3. after the installation completes, reboot (by holding the power down because it hangs while restarting)
4. grub loads as usual, ubuntu login screen appears. but once you hit your keyboard a few times for your password entry it hangs.
5. so once again hold power down to shutdown, and then reboot again.
6. BANG! As soon as the Surface Pro starts, it now reports low battery warning and shuts itself. Battery is full btw. No matter you plug in the charger, the machine is stuck, it always reports the battery low and you're stuck.

That's how I bricked two Surface Pro's in two days. Any help regarding a recovery operation would be great.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Just before i was about to return the machines i wanted to try once more (after 24 hours). To my suprise both machines did boot up this time. There's definitely some sort of bug in some of that uefi code that queries the battery status.

Anyway, i'm glad the machines are back and I think I won't be trying to install Ubuntu natively in a foreseeble time.

Latest update for the record: I couldn't resist and tried to install Ubuntu again a month later. I went with 14.04 daily image and opted for using the entire disk (wiped Windows, no dual-boot), and this time it worked.

Answer (score 0):

The link below might help you get it back up and working again. Good luck.

http://thingsthatmightinterestnerds.com/surfacepro_dumpfactoryimage/

Comment: thanks but that would not work because the machine is stuck at the boot up process, before any OS is even attempted to load.